# Send keys over ssh connection to nano editor

Tags: linux, cron, nano

I have a situation where I am deleting the crontab and then recreate it.
So I do crontab -r and then crontab -e.

The problem I have is that crontab -e opens up nano, and I'd like a command line that can do
crontab -e then send the F3 and F2 keys, which are for save and exit.

I need to this happen since I will be sending the commands via an ssh connection so nano will not be used interactively.

I am doing this to have crontab automatically create itself a brand new crontab file with all correct permissions and header.

Thank you
ionut

Answer (score 1):

No need to use any interactive editor.

Write the new schedule to a *file* and then simply call:

```
crontab  file
```

See the crontab [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab).